# Rewriting a pymc script for parameter estimation in dynamical systems in pymc3

Tags: python, pymc, markov-chains, mcmc, pymc3

I'd like to use pymc3 to estimate unknown parameters and states in a Hodgkin Huxley neuron model. My code in pymc is based off of http://healthyalgorithms.com/2010/10/19/mcmc-in-python-how-to-stick-a-statistical-model-on-a-system-dynamics-model-in-pymc/ and executes reasonably well.

```
#parameter priors
@deterministic
def HH(priors in here)
    #model equations
    #return numpy arrays that somehow contain the probability distributions as elements
    return V,n,m,h

#Make V deterministic in one line. Seems to be the magic that makes this work.
V = Lambda('V', lambda HH=HH: HH[0])

#set up the likelihood
A = Normal('A',mu=V,tau=2.0,value=voltage_data,observed = True)
#run the sampling...
```

In pymc3, the Lambda trick is not available to me. Here is one of my attempts:

```
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as tt
from pymc3 import Model, Normal, Uniform, Deterministic, sample, NUTS, Metropolis, find_MAP
import scipy

#observed data
T = 10
dt = 0.02

voltage_data_file = 'noise_measured.dat'
voltage_data = np.loadtxt(voltage_data_file)
voltage_data = voltage_data[0:T]

current_data_file = 'current.dat'
current_data = np.loadtxt(current_data_file)
current_data = current_data[0:T]

#functions needed later
def x_inf(V,vx,dvx):
    return 0.5*(1 + np.tanh((V - vx)/dvx))
def tau(V,vx_t,dvx_t,tx_0,tx_1):
    return tx_0 + 0.5*tx_1*(1 + np.tanh((V- vx_t)/dvx_t))

#Model
NaKL_Model = Model()
with NaKL_Model:
    #priors
    g_Naa = Uniform('g_Naa',0.0,150.0)
    E_Na = Uniform('E_Na',30.0,70.0)
    g_K = Uniform('g_K',0.0,150.0)
    E_K = Uniform('E_K',-100.0,-50.0)
    g_L = Uniform('g_L',0.1,1.0)
    E_L = Uniform('E_L',-90.0,-50.0)
    vm = Uniform('vm',-60.0,-30.0)
    vm_t = Uniform('vm_t',-60.0,-30.0)
    dvm = Uniform('dvm',10.0,20.0)
    dvm_t = Uniform('dvm_t',10.0,20.0)
    tmm_0 = Uniform('tmm_0',0.05,0.25)
    tm_1 = Uniform('tm_1',0.1,1.0)
    vh = Uniform('vh',-80.0,-40.0)
    vh_t = Uniform('vh_t',-80.0,-40.0)
    dvh = Uniform('dvh',-30.0,-10.0)
    dvh_t = Uniform('dvh_t',-30.0,-10.0)
    th_0 = Uniform('th_0',0.5,1.5)
    th_1 = Uniform('th_1',5.0,9.0)
    vn = Uniform('vn',-70.0,-40.0)
    vn_t = Uniform('vn_t',-70.0,-40.0)
    dvn = Uniform('dvn',10.0,40.0)
    dvn_t = Uniform('dvn_t',10.0,40.0)
    tn_0 = Uniform('tn_0',0.5,1.5)
    tn_1 = Uniform('tn_1',3.0,7.0)
    #Initial Conditions
    V_0 = Uniform('V_0',-100.0,50.0)
    n_0 = Uniform('n_0',0.0,1.0)
    m_0 = Uniform('m_0',0.0,1.0)
    h_0 = Uniform('h_0',0.0,1.0)

    def HH(i,V_current,n_current,m_current,h_current,g_Naa=g_Naa,E_Na=E_Na,g_K=g_K,E_K=E_K,g_L=g_L,E_L=E_L,vm=vm,vm_t=vm_t,dvm=dvm,dvm_t=dvm_t,tmm_0=tmm_0,tm_1=tm_1,vh=vh,vh_t=vh_t,dvh=dvh,dvh_t=dvh_t,th_0=th_0,th_1=th_1,vn=vn,vn_t=vn_t,dvn=dvn,dvn_t=dvn_t,tn_0=tn_0,tn_1=tn_1):

        V_new = V_current + dt*(g_L*(E_L - V_current) + g_K*n_current**4*(E_K - V_current) + g_Naa*m_current**3*h_current*(E_Na - V_current) + current_data[i])

        n_new = n_current + dt*(x_inf(V_current,vn,dvn)-n_current)/tau(V_current,vn_t,dvn_t,tn_0,tn_1)
        m_new = m_current + dt*(x_inf(V_current,vm,dvm)-m_current)/tau(V_current,vm_t,dvm_t,tmm_0,tm_1)
        h_new = h_current + dt*(x_inf(V_current,vh,dvh)-h_current)/tau(V_current,vh_t,dvh_t,th_0,th_1)

        return V_new,n_new,m_new,h_new

    V_state = [V_0]
    n_state = [n_0]
    m_state = [m_0]
    h_state = [h_0]

    #A = [Normal('A0',mu=V_0,tau=2.0,observed = voltage_data[0])]
    for i in range(1,T):
        V_state.append(Deterministic('V' + str(i), HH(i-1,V_state[i-1],n_state[i-1],m_state[i-1],h_state[i-1])[0]))
        n_state.append(Deterministic('V' + str(i), HH(i-1,V_state[i-1],n_state[i-1],m_state[i-1],h_state[i-1])[1]))
        m_state.append(Deterministic('V' + str(i), HH(i-1,V_state[i-1],n_state[i-1],m_state[i-1],h_state[i-1])[2]))
        h_state.append(Deterministic('V' + str(i), HH(i-1,V_state[i-1],n_state[i-1],m_state[i-1],h_state[i-1])[3]))
        #A.append(Normal('A' + str(i),mu=V_state[i],sd=2.0,observed = voltage_data[0]))
    A = Normal('A',mu=V_state,sd=2.0,observed = voltage_data)
    start = find_MAP()
    #step = NUTS(scaling=start)
    step = Metropolis(start=start)
    trace = sample(100,step)
```

The only other example that I've seen asked on these forums is here: [Simple Dynamical Model in PyMC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247074/simple-dynamical-model-in-pymc3)

However, that doesn't help answer my question because neither proposed solution there works. My solution doesn't work either - I don't get an error, but when I run the script the sampling appears never to start. In any case, my solution seems inefficient because I have to run a python for loop to define all of the Deterministic distributions. I'm not sure if pymc3 even recognizes the way I've put them all in a pure python list. If my function HH() could return a numpy array or some kind of theano object, maybe that would help. But I'm lost as to how to implement it.

Comment: Can you make some example data files so that I can try running your code?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some tips.

Comment: Of course! That is a good suggestion. I am not so concerned whether the parameters are estimated correctly at this stage. If the algorithm ran, that would be wonderful.

Here is the noisy data to be assimilated for the estimation procedure:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4k8uufa0c4m9up/noise_measured.dat?dl=0

Here is the injected current for the model. Please use the model equations in the code box. I've updated them by removing a factor of 0.8 from one of the equations to make it work with this current:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/urle5ionq2ti84o/current.dat?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works for me, after a tiny change in the last two lines to read:

```
step = Metropolis()
trace = sample(100, step, start=start)
```

It takes a while, though, so you can make `T` smaller if you want to see results sooner.

Here is [a notebook that shows it in action](https://gist.github.com/aflaxman/c492d4fc349677d690ee).

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts. I hope it will be helpful to others.
I think my formulation is clunky and inefficient. The code based in pymc (rather than pymc3) is much faster. I expect that someone who understands pymc3 better than I do could write much faster code.